# Java generic class and SortedSet<of generic class>

Tags: java, generics

First of all, this is a homework exercise where I don't get what statement refers exactly to, maybe this is why is the only undone exercise.

I have to create one generic class with a single attribute - totalNumberOfItems with methods which enables the user to set and return an entry.

In main(), I have to create a `SortedSet<of my generic class>` variable which maintains all the items.

I need to use add/addAll, return specific item or check if one item exist in my set.

```
SortedSet<VirtualLibrary> myLibrary = new TreeSet<VirtualLibrary>();
    //String Book(author, String title, int numberOfPages, int year, String genre)
    myLibrary.add(new Book("Author", "title", 300, 1930, "genre"));
```

This is my code in main, Book is a separated class which extends an item / entry class which my generic class extends.

```
public class VirtualLibrary<T extends Entry> {
int totalNumberOfEntries = 0;
```

and I tried to @Override add method like this:

```
@Override
void add(T object) {
    totalNumberOfEntries++;
}
```

The problem is the following: `add(VirtualLibrary) in type Set<VirtualLibrary> is not applicable for the argument Book` and also I could not Override add method in my generic class.

How should this one look to be good? Should I create an interface instead of class?

Comment: Are you trying to add a Book to a Set of libraries? That doesn't sound right to me. Shouldn't the VirtualLibrary contain a Set of Books (or a Set of Entry)?

Comment: `SortedSet<VirtualLibrary> myLibrary = new TreeSet<VirtualLibrary>();` doesn't make much sense. Set is container for elements of some type, in your case container for *possibly many* libraries, but `myLibrary` suggests that this variable holds *one* library (if you meant it to hold many libraries you should use plural form like *myLibrarie**s***). So what is the purpose of this variable (if it should represent single library then `SortedSet<VirtualLibrary>` is incorrect type, since you want it to hold books maybe use `SortedSet<Book>`).

Comment: @Eran , yes, a set of Entry would be more likely. maybe this is the point, I'm just overthinking this, probably I should only instantiate object using the generic class and increment the number of entries, but still, what would be the role of that counter as long as my set supports size() at every moment?

Comment: @Pshemo ,  I have multiple classes like Books, Articles, Magazines which all extend one Entry class. So, my generic extends the Entry class. So, there is no way to have one Set with different object's type?

Comment: If you have `Set<Animal>` then as long as `Dog extends Animal` you can add `Dog` to that set, so having `Set<Entry>` should allow you to place `Book` `Article` `Magazine` in it as long as they `extends Entry`.